# Why transforming step-area to scatter type chart gives an empty chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization, c3.js

I am new to c3.js and working on transforming type of chart from step-area to scatter and vice versa. 
Whenever I transform step-area to scatter there are no scatter points visible and whenever I transform scatter to step-area there are some extra points visible on the steps.

Here is a fiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/xxjrmm53/4/

```
var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#test',
    data: {
        xs: {
            setosa: 'setosa_x',
            versicolor: 'versicolor_x',
        },
        // iris data from R
        columns: [
            ["setosa_x", 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3.0, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3.0, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3.0, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3],
            ["versicolor_x", 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2.0, 3.0, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3.0, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 2.8, 3.0, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3.0, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3.0, 2.5, 2.6, 3.0, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8],
            ["setosa", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
            ["versicolor", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3],
        ],
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            label: 'Sepal.Width',
            tick: {
                fit: false
            }
        },
        y: {
            label: 'Petal.Width'
        }
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart1.transform("area-step");
}, 3000);
```

Please, help me understanding where I went wrong?
Thanks in advance.